# Revised Simplex Method w/o Identity Matrix

Tags: linear-programming

For a homework problem we're forced into using revised simplex, but I cannot seem to even get past the first step. My biggest problem is:

```
max z = 2x1 + 3x2 -x3 
subject to: 
x1 + 2x2 <= 3 
2x1 + 3x2 <= 6 
3x1 + 2x2 + x3 = 10
```

I know that this goes into:

```
max z = 2x1 + 3x2 -x3
subject to: 
x1 + 2x2 + x4 = 3
2x1 + 3x2 + x5 = 6
3x1 + 2x2 + x3 =10
```

But because the last row doesn't need a slack variable (since there's an equals and adding a x6 would make this invalid), I'm left with 2 columns of a identity matrix size 3 to put as b. My foundations are a bit shaky at LP's but is it possible I can shift the constraints around? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can add an artificial variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite the equality in the last row as a pair of inequalties.